# Ayuda con JQuery - Confirm

Tags: jquery

Buen día foro. Alguna sugerencia para poder realizar la ejecución de eliminación mediante un confirm de jquery.

Mi eliminación la realizo mediante php y lo pretendo ejecutar debajo $.alert('Prospecto Eliminado'). Mi duda es mediante que proceso puedo ejecutar mi código php para que se realice la eliminación. He intentado con una función y ajax pero no me resulta, alguna sugerencia. De antemano gracias.

[image: Código de generación de confirm]

Comment: Hola Ever! mediante ajax te debería funcionar. Deberías agregar tu archivo php para ver si el error no se encuentra ahí. De todas formas si agregaras una función Ajax dentro del action: function() {//agregar ajax aquí} pasándole el id del elemento a eliminar debería funcionar correctamente. Si no sabes usar ajax dimelo y te dejo un ejemplo. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Vas por buen camino usando JQuery y de hecho debería ser sencillo usando algo como (en lugar del $.alert...):

```
$.post( "eliminar.php", {id:$("#inputDeIdAEliminar").value} function( data ) {
  if(data=="OK"){
      //tu codigo para eliminar el div o control donde tienes la información
      //del registro eliminado va aquí.
      alert("Registro Eliminado");
  }else{
      alert("Ocurrió el siguiente error: "+data);
  }
});
```

En tu php recibirías:

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
   //todo tu codigo para eliminar el registro.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**espero te sirva este ejemplo:**

agrega esto en el js

```
 function delete()
{
  var x = confirm("estas seguro de eliminar este usuario?");
  if (x){
      return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

en el html agrega la funcion y la enlasas con el evento click

```
<input type="button" Onclick="delete()">
```

dentro del if en el true ya puedes manejarlo como desees si quieres manejarlo con ajax tambien lo puedes hacer.